# How Can I Get Twilio to send out an SMS to someone other than myself

Tags: twilio, zapier

I've been testing Twilio SMS and can only get it to send texts to myself.  I've heard this is a common issue but I can't seem to find the workaround for this.  Any advice would be helpful.  (I'm trying to set it up to send client automated notifications from within a simple Zapier integration).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely using a Trial account, you should move to Paid account.
https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136107-How-does-Twilio-s-Free-Trial-work-